# Why CORS request succeeds even if Access-Control-Allow-Headers is missing?

Tags: jquery, http, http-headers, cors

Quote from [Opera documentation](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/dom-access-control-using-cross-origin-resource-sharing/#AccessControlAllowHeaders) (first link i've found):

> Standard or custom headers are appropriate values for
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers. For the cross-origin request to succeed,
>   its value must match (or include) the value of the
>   Access-Control-Request-Headers header.

I'm sending a request using jQuery. If i comment out `setRequestHeader`:

```js
$(function() {            
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://silex.local/users',
        method: 'GET',
        beforeSend : function(req) {
            //req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'FID ds7sd6:32n8942b3672n2');
        }
    });
});
```

It shouldn't work, since the **server is responding** with:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Sat, 11 Aug 2012 02:15:14 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) PHP/5.3.14
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.14
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

While client is **requesting with**:

```
GET http://silex.local/users HTTP/1.1
Host: silex.local
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: it-it,it;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://localhost/test.html
Origin: http://localhost
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

What i'm missing? Sorry if this is an odd question, first time with CORS for me...

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`  means that the resource can be accessed by any domain in a cross-site manner. [You can read more about this on the MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Yep, but i'm talking about `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you misunderstand what `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` does (that poorly-worded quote doesn't help).  It allows the server to tell the browser which headers are *acceptable* for cross-Origin XHR requests to set.

It does not mean that those headers are *mandatory*.  If a script doesn't set a header, the request is still allowed to happen.

Comment: Mhm.. thanks. That's a big error in Opera doc? Because "For the cross-origin request to succeed, its value must match  the value of the Access-Control-Request-Headers header." It's saying exactly `mandatory`.

Comment: I think it's trying to say that if your script tries to set a header that's not in the set allowed by `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, then the request will fail.  (Although I wonder if it will actually fail or just not send the header.)